# CSS Checkbox duplicate

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I struggle with styling checkboxes. Can anyone tell me why the standard checkbox is still being shown alongside the custom box? I have had this problem before due to an unwanted space in the CSS however i cannot see that problem this time.

CSS

```
/*CHECKBOX STYLING*/
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
  display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
  padding-left:27px;
  height:22px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:22px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0 0;
  font-size:22px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
  background-position:0 -22px;
}

label.css-label {
  background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_ca0ba5f8e61aa87173232fcf5ce5eac5.png);
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="css-checkbox" style="display:inline" type="checkbox" id="chair" name="option" onClick="showHideChair(this,'myChair')"><label class="css-label" for="chair">Chair</label>


            <input class="css-checkbox"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mFHTM/3/ This is my Fiddle

Answer (score 3):

Inline CSS has the greatest [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), therefore it outweighs your other CSS. Get rid of the `style="display:inline"`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mFHTM/6/)**

Per the MDN:

> The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Universal selectors
> - Type selectors
> - Class selectors
> - Attributes selectors
> - Pseudo-classes
> - ID selectors
> - **Inline style**

Answer (score 2):

In the `HTML` you're putting `style='display:inline;` which is overwriting the `display:none;`.

I took out

```
style='display:none;'
```

from the HTML.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mFHTM/5/)

Refer to [j08691's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21859734/2471423) to find out why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `display` style of your checkbox is being overridden when you use `style='display:inline;` in your HTML, by convention inline CSS will override external CSS.

You can either remove `display:inline;` from your HTML or use `!important` attribute here:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {                     
    display:none !important;                    
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFHTM/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css.

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-ms-appearance:none;
appearance:none
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/mFHTM/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take it out the flow and hide from screen:

```
 input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
        position:absolute;
        left:-9999px;
    }
```

If input and label are here with the right attributes , it is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/mFHTM/8/

Answer (score 0):

try this
**easiest way**

**CSS**

```
.test_1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.myCheckbox input {
    display: none;
}

.myCheckbox span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background:#00F;
}

.myCheckbox input:checked + span {
    background:#0F0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="test">Label for my styled "checkbox"</label>
<label class="myCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test"/>
    <span style="border:#666 1px solid;">.</span>
</label>
```